# How could i use 'popover' to display an enlarged image acquired from an input file? (jQuery/bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, bootstrap-4

Currently, i have this program which asks the user for a couple of inputs (entered using a modal), one of the inputs being of type file, restricted to images only. All of the inputs are shown in a dynamic table. I need to be able to enlarge the image within the table upon hovering over it (mouseover). Here is an example of how it is suppose to look when working;

[image]

below is my jQuery for adding the inputs to the HTML table:

```
//function that adds input values to the table
function addToTable() {
  //add tbody tag if one is not present
  if($("#inputTable tBody").length == 0) {
    $("#inputTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
  }

  $(function() {
    $('#insertImage').on('change', function()
    {
      var filePath = $(this).val();
      console.log(filePath);
    });
  });

var imageLocation = $("#insertImage").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, "images/");

  //append inputs to the Table
  $("#inputTable tbody").append(
    "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + "<img src=" + imageLocation + " class=image" + ">" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + $("#addName").val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + $("#addSurname").val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
        "<button type='button' " +
          "class='btn'><i class='fas fa-user-edit' id='pencilIcon'></i></button>" +
      "<td>" +
        "<button type='button' " +
          "onclick='openModal(); deleteData(this);'" +
          "class='btn'><i class='fas fa-dumpster' id='dumpsterIcon'></i></button>" +
        "</button>" +
      "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );
}
```

Below is the input asking for the image (HTML):

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="insertImage">Insert Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" name="insertImage" id="insertImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" aria-describedby="inputHelp">
              </div>
```

Here is the jQuery function i planned on using to get this popover working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
          //trigger: 'focus',
          trigger: 'hover',
          html: true,
          content: function () {
                return '<img class="img-fluid" src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';
          },
          title: 'Toolbox'
    }) 
});
```

If anyone has any idea on how i may be able to incorporate the above function to work with my code, id greatly appreciate it!